Update img src onclick for first available selection spot
I am trying to make an image selector using javascript. I have a grid of images and I plan on making them use the onclick function. I want users to be able to select up to five of those images. As they are selected, I want the placeholder images for the 5 selections to update to show the image that was selected. I know how to update the placeholder images, but I'm not sure how to create an onclick function that will choose the first available spot. I also need them to be able to click a selection to remove it, so the available spots might not be in order. For example, if they make five selections, but then they remove the middle selection and select a new one, I need it to go to the empty spot. I also need the function to do nothing if all five spots are full. Any suggestions for the best way to do this would be appreciated.
Current sample code:
<center>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture1.png' title='Picture 1' id='picture1' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture2.png' title='Picture 2' id='picture2' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture3.png' title='Picture 3' id='picture3' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture4.png' title='Picture 4' id='picture4' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture5.png' title='Picture 5' id='picture5' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture6.png' title='Picture 6' id='picture6' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture7.png' title='Picture 7' id='picture7' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture8.png' title='Picture 8' id='picture8' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture9.png' title='Picture 9' id='picture9' width='40'>
  <img src='images/portraits/picture10.png' title='Picture 10' id='picture10' width='40'>
  <h3>Selections:</h3>
  <img src="images/portraits/placeholder.png" width="60" id="selection1">
  <img src="images/portraits/placeholder.png" width="60" id="selection2">
  <img src="images/portraits/placeholder.png" width="60" id="selection3">
  <img src="images/portraits/placeholder.png" width="60" id="selection4">
  <img src="images/portraits/placeholder.png" width="60" id="selection5">
</center>


Loop over the placeholder images, until you get one that has placeholder.png in its src. Replace its src with the selected image.

When they remove an image, put back the placeholder URL. So the next time they click on an image, it will be found as the first available spot.

Well the first solution that jumps to mind, is checking if one of the thumbnails has a SRC. if it does then you can safely skip to the next one.
Then all you need to do is loop until you find one that doesn't have a src set.


const thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

for (let i = 0 ; i < thumbnails.length; i++ ){
  let thumbnail = thumbnails[i];
  if( thumbnail.src !== ""){
    // your code here
       break;
  }
} 
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail">
</div>



